# Matching counts of multiple columns between two tables

Tags: sql

I want to check the counts of the following columns between two tables based on 
 (COMPANY_CODE+AGENT+AGENT_LEVEL+MARKET_CODE+START_DATE+STOP_DATE)

```
02           1000000    101           60       BASE     20110303    20170303
02           1000001    101           60       BASE     20110303    20170303
02           1000002    101           60       BASE     20110303    20170303
02           1000003    101           60      BASE      20110303    20170303

COMPANY_COD POLICY_NUMBER AGENT AGENT_LEVEL MARKET_CODE START_DATE STOP_DATE
01           0000001    100           80       BASE     20100303    20180303
01           0000002    100           80       BASE     20100303    20180303
01           0000003    100           80       BASE     20100303    20180303
01           0000004    100           80       BASE     20100303    20180303
```

Comment: Please stop ***SHOUTING AT US!*** Writing your question in ALL CAPS is annoying, because it's really hard to read, and writing in ALL CAPS is generally considered SHOUTING at your audience, which is just plain rude and offensive. Don't do that! And fix your post ASAP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the rows in the two tables, use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select COMPANY_CODE, AGENT, AGENT_LEVEL, MARKET_CODE, START_DATE, STOP_DATE, sum(in_1), sum_in_2)
from ((select COMPANY_CODE, AGENT, AGENT_LEVEL, MARKET_CODE, START_DATE, STOP_DATE, 1 as in_1, 0 as in_2
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select COMPANY_CODE, AGENT, AGENT_LEVEL, MARKET_CODE, START_DATE, STOP_DATE, 2 as in_1, 1 as in_2
       from t2
      ) 
     ) t
group by COMPANY_CODE, AGENT, AGENT_LEVEL, MARKET_CODE, START_DATE, STOP_DATE
having sum(in_1) <> sum(in_2);
```

The `having` clause returns the values that are in one or not the other.  Or that are in the two tables a different number of times.